# obtain asp.net iframe src= database field

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

I have a database table setup with a column that holds the name of a pdf file.  I load the table elements from MS Sql Server and can display them.  The issue I have is how to load the Brochure data element that holds the name of the pdf file into the Iframe SRC field.

I can hardcode the line like this and it works fine:
`<iframe id ="iframeBrochure" runat="server" style="height:800px; width:750px" src="Brochure1.pdf" ></iframe>`

The dataelement that I want to use I can display like this:
`<td><asp:Label ID="lbBrochure" runat="server" Text="LabelLabel"></asp:Label></td>`

Comes back as Brochure1.pdf

How do I set the Iframe src equal to lbBrochure?

When I try putting it in quotes it comes back as a literal.  /csportal/lbBrochure

Instead I need it to pass "Brochure1.pdf", which is stored in the /csportal directory.

Thanks in advance,
Allen

Answer (score 0):

`<iframe id="iframeBrochure" src="<%= pathToPdf %>" />`

Where `pathToPdf` is a String value accessible from your aspx or ascx, such as an exposed field in the parent Page subclass. There is no need for the `runat=""` attribute on the iframe.

Alternately, if you want to use HtmlGenericControl on the iframe, then like so:

`<iframe id="iframeBrochure" runat="server" />`

And from your Page subclass (i.e. code-behind) this:

`this.iframeBrochure.Attributes["src"] = pathToPdf;`

Comment: Houston!  We have PDF!  Thank you!!

Comment: iframeBrochure.Attributes("src") = part.Brochure